# MYSQL Left join A.table and b.table while retaining a.table id

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

MYSQL Left join A.table and b.table while retaining a.table id when there is no b.table match.

```
SELECT * FROM sales_customer a LEFT JOIN sales_contact b
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN company_name = '' THEN lname ELSE company_name END ASC
```

Gets me this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 54
  [customer_id] => 
)
```

When there is no b.table match.

I need this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 54
  [customer_id] => 29 
)
```

Any suggestions?

The solution below worked. Thanks for your help.

SELECT *, COALESCE(a.customer_id, 0) AS customer_id FROM sales_customer a LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_contact b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN company_name = '' THEN lname ELSE company_name END ASC

Comment: Do `SELECT [0], [a.customer_id]`

Comment: That statement seems 100% logical however I cant seem to get the syntax to work correctly. Replace the SELECT * with your suggestion?

Comment: @ruakh covered it better than I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COALESCE(b.customer_id, 0) AS customer_id
FROM sales_customer a 
LEFT JOIN sales_contact b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN company_name = '' THEN lname ELSE company_name END ASC
```

Comment: Ok, first i would like to thank everyone for their help. Second the answer that worked best for me was actually a variation of this one. Ill post the solution above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using COALESCE().  It will return the first non-NULL value.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the OP's problem. `a.customer_id` will never be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `SELECT *` ("select all fields"), you should specify the fields you actually want: `` SELECT 54 AS `0`, a.customer_id, ... FROM ... ``. That's better practice in general, not just for this.

If you *really* want to write `SELECT *` to select all fields, you can still add additional fields to the end, which in PHP will overwrite earlier like-named fields: `SELECT *, a.customer_id FROM ...`.

Comment: Got it, and I should have known this. Practice makes perfect. Thanks for your help.